# 2-way binding for directive not working

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a custom Angular directive, and it has an isolated scope having a value base mapped as 2-way binding
base="="

From the parent scope I pass base to directive as

and in the directive controller I am modifying this base value. The base is not just an object but a json structure having arrays within itself. I transverse to few fields inside base and then change those field value. For example one field is changed from 0 to 1.

Now, In another method in parent controller, I pick this base from original JSON, from where it was passed to directive. I expect the values changed in directive to be reflected in original JSON object.

Unfortunately that's not happening. I guess 2-way binding prefixes should make it possible. 
I am sorry, since the directive template is too big, I am not currently uploading it. I will try uploading a miniature version later if possible.

In the meanwhile, Am I going wrong somewhere, Is there specifically something that needs to be done.?

A working fiddle illustrating this might help. I googled out and found something known as $broadcast and $emit. I am not sure how to use them in this case, and also I have never used them before.

Expecting little help guys..

Edit:

```
return {
            scope: {
                parent: '='
                item: '=',

            },
controller: 'ctrlname',
templateUrl:'tplname',
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
}
```

in html something like:

```
<li ng-repeat= l in originalJSON>
  -----------something here------
   <li ng-repeat= base in l>
   ---------something here-------
       <li ng-repeat="x in base.y">
<div layout="row" layout-wrap directive-name  parent="base"  item="item" ></div>
</li>
</li>
</li>
```

Sorry it was '='

Just to add one more important info. In the parent controller, I am trying to access the **originalJSON** and looking for modified field in the base field inside it.

Comment: Will you upload your directive html line and just the isolated scope section of your directive?

Comment: provide relevant code

Comment: '@' is for one way binding, for 2-way use '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is multiple directives binding two ways to the same object.

This line appears several times (equal to the number of items in base):

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap directive-name  parent="base"  item="item" ></div>
```

So you have several two way bindings between parent and base. These are all sitting in a for loop which will be watching base for any changes and updating the loop as necessary. I imagine that this could easily cause issues in your code.

Perhaps, you can bind to x instead?

Edit to clarify (as requested by comment): 
You have your 'base' object which is being updated, this is using two way binding on multiple directives. Thus, you have: 
base object 'a' being kept in sync with object 'b' in directive 1. 
base object 'a' being kept in sync with object 'c' in directive 2.
base object 'a' being kept in sync with object 'd' in directive 3.

and so on in your for-loop. Then, as your directives are being processed, you have some logic to update b,c and d - which in turn you expect to update a. These events will probably all be firing at the same time. Each time they do fire, your for loop, which is looping over elements in a, recognises that 'a' has changed and says 'lets calculate the results of this for loop again'. Then each of the directives are going to be created again - perhaps firing off some more logic to change a. 
There is not enough information in your question to tell that this is the problem, but hopefully you can see from my description that race conditions could be problem here. Binding to x in your for-loop instead (and having a one way binding to the base object if it is needed) should be a safer way of achieving what you want.

Comment: Your answer made me worried. what kind of issues do you see here. I will be grateful if you could let me know in advance. I am new to angular and don't have that good foresight.

Comment: Updated. Have you tried binding to x? It should be a simple way to see if this solves your issue.

Comment: Also, I would suggest adding a watch statement ($watchCollection) in the directive and the controller - this can then simply log out the JSON stating the newValue and oldValue when it changes

Comment: Thanx Sam for your efforts to clarify...My inputs b, c, d and so on..are changed by user typing only. So hopefully there will be no race conditions (given user can type one input box at a time). Anyways, i got your point and appreciate your efforts

Comment: Great, I hope I helped in some way

Answer (score 1):

Can't you share the base object using services/factories. Also is the parent scope a directive?

Comment: No. parent scope is a ctrl

Comment: you could move the scope out of the control to a service

Answer (score 0):

@ is not a two way binding, for two way binding you need to use =

```
scope: {
     "twoway": "=" // two way binding
  },
```